# Negate &nbsp; with regex

Tags: php, regex

Trying to negate `&nbsp;` string but nothing seems to work..

Heres what im trying to do:

Input:

```
example: word1&nbsp;word2
```

Output that i want:

```
example: ****&nbsp;word2
```

Current code:

```
preg_replace('/example: (\s|.nbsp;)?[^<\n\r (&nbsp;)]*', 'example: ****', $sContent);
```

From what i understand, `[^<\n\r (&nbsp;)]` needs to change. Currently it takes every symbol from `&nbsp;` separately, i want it to take the whole string. How can i do that?

Comment: Your code works fine: https://eval.in/83288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `.*?` to match everything before the `&nbsp;` and use capture groups to put back everything else:

```
preg_replace('/(example: ).*?(&nbsp;)/', '$1****$2', $sContent);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iK2pK4)

Or you can use lookarounds to avoid capture groups...

```
preg_replace('/(?<=example: ).*?(?=&nbsp;)/', '****', $sContent);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/oL7kP3)

Comment: Thanks, i think the 2nd variant was what i was looking for.

Comment: @Edgar You're welcome! Could you tell me why you used `.nbsp;` and `<` in your regex? Do you perhaps have some restrictions on what to match? (dot is a wildcard and will match any character except newlines)

Comment: Yeah i had some restrictions other than '&nbsp;', for example my input could have ended like so "<b>example: word1</b>nsbp;word2". So in this example i would need to stop before the '<' sign. I had trouble detecting the 'nbsp;' string, but your answer will help me solve my problem.